# android sending succesfully textview's text as a sms but receiving invalid chars on other emulator

Tags: android, sms

I want to clearly explain what i did. I have a one listactivity which stores prepared messages like "Call me later!", "I will come soon"... When the user click the item, listitem (object) goes to other intent's textview via `getintent().getserializable("comingstring");`now textview stores this string via `textview.setText(getintent().getserializable("comingstring").toString())` . There is no any problem here. I enter phone number(5554) which is other emulator, **message is succesfully delivered but problem is when i look emulator 5554's inbox, i see the delivered message like " @ { & !'  = | that kind of chars.** Can you show me a solution? (I also tried sending prepared message(listitem's object) via mms.apk but the result is fail again. Message has succesfully sent but when i read other emulator's receiving message in inbox, i see only silly chars.)

Messages come from listactivity. **In listactivity**:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages); 
setListAdapter(adapter); 

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long rowid) {
            itemMesaj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            SmsActivity.putExtra("itemMesaj", itemMesaj);
            startActivity(SmsActivity);
 }
```

**In SmsActivity**

```
itemMesaj =  (String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("itemMesaj");txtMesaj = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmesaj);txtMesaj.setText(itemMesaj);

public void onClick(View src) {
switch (src.getId()) {
case R.id.btnSend:
     messageinsend = txtMesaj.getText().toString();  
     Log.d("messagecheck", messageinsend);
     sendSMS("5556", messageinsend);
    break;
default:
    break;
```

}

I benefit sendSMS method from http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android. As i say, there is no problem for sending sms or receving only problem is receving text has invalid chars like **" @ { & !' = |**. If i try to send sendSms("5556","TRYING SOME TEXT") like this, there is no problem from receving side. I see the text like TRYING SOME TEXT.

Comment: peek at the relevant code can give a hint.

Comment: I hope you can solve it. I can not find where the problem is.

Comment: Quick peak at problem. Text Messagees supports 3 encodings: [GSM 03.38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38), [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and 8-bit encoding (taken from wiki). Maybe your phone is not set to properly decode charecters?

Comment: why are you passing the whole textview to the smsactivity.. just the text is enough..

Comment: Is the messagecheck log showing correct message?

Comment: need to see sendSms method. Also the code where you receive the sms.

Comment: yes there is no problem on log. log message is same with the textview's text.

Comment: sms is receving from mms.apk 's inbox. I only use sendSms method from this site:  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android. I m passing listitem which is text to smsactivity. Because, user choose telephone number from telephony directory and seeing textview which was selected from list. Then textview.getText() is going to sendSMS("5556",textview.getText());

Answer (score 0):

The problem is while creating/getting the message from the listview. 

Instead of this

```
itemMesaj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Try this

```
itemMesaj = adapter.getItem(position);
```

EDIT:

In onItemClick() paramters `View v` is the clicked view. So you can use that too to get the sms text.  Like

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v;
String message = tv.gettext();
```